# How to remove single quote in filename while moving to the file using php

Tags: php

While uploading a file which contain single quote, when it moved to folder it add a \ in it. How to remove this slash using PHP

eg. my file which has a name video's.mp4
I remove slash and save it into mysql database but it moved to the folder contain video/s.mp4.

When i try to download in frontend it showing that FILE NOT FOUND.

I use following code to remove the slash :

```
<?php
$remove[] = "'";
$name = str_replace( $remove, "", $name ); //name is file name i.e. videp's.mp4
?>
```

Comment: You can replace some set of such characters with underscore(_).

Comment: As Disha V. said, you can manipulate the filename. In fact IMO it is good to rename them to something unpredictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `$name` value comes from submitted form, it may have quotes escaped by the slash. Use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) before replacing the quote:

```
<?php
$remove[] = "'";
$name = str_replace( $remove, "", stripslashes( $name ) ); //name is file name i.e. videp's.mp4
?>
```